# R, GenomicRanges: find the width of overlapping genomic ranges

Tags: r, overlap, bioconductor

Given two GenomicRanges like:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

gr1 <- 
  makeGRangesFromDataFrame(
    data.frame(
      chr = c("1","1","2","2"),
      start = c(10,50,10,50),
      end = c(20,60,20,60)
    )
  )

gr2 <- 
  makeGRangesFromDataFrame(
    data.frame(
      chr = c("2","2","3","3"),
      start = c(15,40,10,50),
      end = c(25,55,20,60)
    )
  )
```

I need to find the overlapping size (width) of the overlapping segments. In my case this would be 5 (for gr1[3] and gr2[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685802/width-of-the-overlapped-segment-in-genomicranges-package)) and 5 (for gr[4] and gr2[2]). The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685802/width-of-the-overlapped-segment-in-genomicranges-package) using `ranges()` on the hit class does not fit with GenomicRanges class (it seems):

```
mm <- findOverlaps(gr1,gr2)
ranges(mm,gr1,gr2)
```

> Error in .local(x, ...) : 
>     'query' must be a Ranges of length equal to number of queries

One would like that there would be a parameter to `GenomicRanges::subsetByOverlaps()` that literally slices and return the overlap.

UPDATE (see below): the solution is in the package itself, `GenomicRanges::intersect()`, so:

```
width(intersect(gr1, gr2))
```

Comment: Is this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33272941/496803 - and the subsequently linked answer any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GenomicRanges package has a specific function for this it seems, `intersect()`. So the solution is rather simple:

```
width(intersect(gr1, gr2))
```

> [1] 6 6

(which is correct)